# What's the difference between sumOf() and sumBy() in Kotlin 1.4?

Tags: kotlin, collections, kotlin-stdlib

How is the new `sumOf()` function in Kotlin 1.4 different from `sumBy()` or `sumByDouble()` functions?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**TLDR**: there's no difference, and eventually `sumBy`/`sumByDouble` can be deprecated in favor of the single `sumOf`.

`sumOf` operation has overloads for different numeric types returned from the selector function. It's something that was impossible previously with the old type inference facility, so in order to handle different numeric types it was required to have functions with the different names: `sumBy` to sum ints, `sumByDouble` to sum doubles, etc.

When the new inference has finally arrived with the experimental support of overload resolution by selector lambda return type, we've decided not to overload the existing `sumBy` function, but to introduce a new operation `sumOf`. This way it has less chance of breaking something and is more consistent in naming with the new operations `list.minOf/maxOf { selector }`.

Comment: You saw it coming 2 years before!! I can now report that `sumBy()` is now deprecated in favor of of `sumOf()` as rightly predicated by Ilya.

Answer (score 6):

As [the Kotlin 1.4 changelog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/07/kotlin-1-4-m3-is-out-standard-library-changes/#collection-operations) states:

> ... `sumOf` lets you **handle sums of different types in the same way**.
> it produces sums of the types `Int`, `Long`,
> `Double`, ... [depending on the return type of the given lambda].